# Create a script rotating backup on remote disk

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, rsync, mysql-python

Firstly, I'm completely lost when it comes to shell scripting so I'm expecting a fairly easy solution to this. I just don't know where to find it.

The situation is this: We are running an application from which we take backups (duh!). The application comes with it's own backup script which when run creates a folder with the current date and time as name. Within these are a database dump and some config files like such:

```
# cd backup
# ll
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  6 02:30 2012-03-06_02-15 
# ll 2012-03-06_02-15
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26706579 Mar  6 02:16 Application.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      26060 Mar  6 02:15 Config.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5503574530 Mar  6 02:21 DatabaseBackup.sql.gz
```

The backup folder is then rsync'd to a network drive.

The script also allows an argument for the number of days backup to keep. Which is great. But now we're starting to see concerns with disk space on the production server.

Replicating the scripts functionallity to dump the database and compress the configs isn't a problem.

But where I get lost is here: I would ideally like to keep the latest backup on the production server, and keep X backups on the network drive.

I'm thinking this shouldn't be too hard using bash (or maybe expect?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will delete everything except the most recent item in a directory:

```
ls -lrt | grep -v total | awk '{print $9}' | head -n -1 | xargs rm
```

If you require X number of remaining items you can alter `head -n -1` to `head -n -X`

Comment: So basically I could use the following chain of commands: 1 dump and compress database. 2 copy latest dump to backup drive. 3 run your command with -n -1 on local drive. 4 run your command with -n -5 on the remote drive. Thus leaving me with the latest copy locally and the 5 latest remotely?

Comment: Yep. The advantage of this method is that no mater how many times the script is run you will always have the X most recent files.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of piping I would use the find command.

Something like: `find /path/to/backups -mtime +1 -exec rm {}  \;` on the production server and the same command with a higher -mtime on the backup server. IBM has a [great resource for using find](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-find.html) at their developerworks site for further reading.